# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' -laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am aware this question has been asked many times and i have tried all other solutions but doesn't work for me.

I am trying to insert data into my database using csv file but then i get this error below

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in
>   'field list' (SQL: insert into `group_item`  (`group_id`,
>   `created_at`, `item_id`, `name`, `price`, `updated_at`) values (1,
>   2017-11-21 15:44:57, 0, Powder, 120, 2017-11-21 15:44:57)

I don't have `name` column in `group_item` but i do have name in `item table`. In the error above, it shows the name column and the results show clearly that the csv file matches the column. Why am i still getting this error.

Could this be from my model?  Below is my model

**Item**

```
  public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group','group_item','item_id','group_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Group**

```
public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item','group_item','group_id','item_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function import($id, Request $request)
{


   $group = Group::whereId($id)->firstorFail();


   #import files into category table
   if($request->file('imported-file'))
   {
             $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
             $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader)
       {
             })->get();

       if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
       {
         foreach ($data->toArray() as $row)
         {
           if(!empty($row))
           {
             $dataArray[] =
             [
               'name' => $row['name'],
               'price' => $row['price'],

             ];
           }
       }

       if(!empty($dataArray))
       {
          $group->items()->attach($dataArray);
         //group->items()->save(new App\Item($dataArray));


        }
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see the CSV being uploaded (at least the headers) along with the code to parse the CSV and the insert action (`->save()`, `->update()`, `->attach()`, etc etc); with what you've shown currently, it's gonna be hard for us to help.

Comment: how are you creating the entities?

Comment: If you don't have 'name' column in group_item, why do you pass it as parameter in the insert?

Comment: @TimLewis please check how i save my data

Comment: @s.dallapalma, look at my update. I am passing that to `item table` actually

Comment: `$group->items()->attach($dataArray);` will try to save information into `group_items`, not `items`. You're gonna want to save the item first then attach it to `$group`. The way you have it commented out is close, but `new App\Item` should be `App\Item::create($dataArray)` (I think) Also, any pivot data should be separate when using attach, like `$group->items()->attach($item, [...]);`

Comment: @TimLewis, i don't actually get your point clearly here. If i save it this way, `App\Item::create($dataArray)` how would it know the group the items belong to ?

Comment: `$groups->items()->attach(App\Item::create($dataArray), ["created_at" => ..., "updated_at" => ...])`. This _should_ create the item and attach it to the group you're defining at the top of your script `$group = Group::whereId($id)->firstorFail();` (I'm not sure about the pivot data for timestamps; they may be automatic, they may not be)

Comment: @TimLewis, i get this error `"Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\App\Item' not found"
`

Comment: `\App\Item` then; namespacing issue

Comment: You mean it cannot find the path? @TimLewis

Comment: If you don't import `App\Item` using `use App\Item`, you need to use `\App\Item` to specify absolute path; it's a common issue with namespacing in Laravel.

Comment: after specifying the absolute path `\App\Item`, it throws this error `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: @TimLewis, we have an unfinished business please :)

Comment: Hmm, might be `$group->items()->attach([\App\Item::create($dataArray)->id]);`, since `->attach()` expects an array of ids. Give that a try. And since you're using `->withTimestamps()` on your relationship, you can drop that from the `attach`

Comment: @TimLewis, problem still persist. Same error.

Comment: Try saving the item outside of the `attach()` method, like `$newItem = \App\Item::create($dataArray);` then attaching it via `$group->items()->attach($newItem->id)` or `$group->items()->attach([$newItem->id]);` Beyond that, it'll be up to you to debug.

Comment: Okay thank you.. it didn't work.. I will try to debug